# OperationalError sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table user has no column named Uname

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

i'm making a signup page in flask using a sqlalchemy database where the user inputs his information and than gets directed to the main page, but i'm getting the error listed in the title of my question.

The code below are from 2 different files, the first codeblock is a part of my models.py file and the rest is the entire code from my auth.py file.

here is the code:

```
class user(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    Uname = db.Column(db.String(150), unique = True)
    Fname = db.Column(db.String(150))
    Sname = db.Column(db.String(150))
    bday = db.Column(db.Date)
    Email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique = True)
    Password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    notes = db.relationship('Note')
```

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for
from .models import user
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from . import db

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)
 

# create route to login page and handle POST , GET requests
@auth.route("/login", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        Uname = request.form.get("Uname")
        Password = request.form.get("Password")

    return render_template("login.html")

# create route to Signup page and handle POST , GET requests
@auth.route('/Signup', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def logout():
    if request.method == "POST":
        Uname = request.form.get("Uname")
        Fname = request.form.get("Fname")
        Sname = request.form.get("Sname")
        bday = request.form.get("bday")
        Email = request.form.get("Email")
        Password = request.form.get("Password")
        ConPassword = request.form.get("ConPassword")

        # signup conditions...
        if len(Fname) < 2:
            flash("Your name is to short", category='error')
        elif Password != ConPassword:
            flash("Your Confirmation Password does not match", category='error')
        elif len(Password) <5:
            flash("Your Password is to short", category='error')
        else:
            new_user = user(Uname=Uname, Fname=Fname, Sname=Sname, bday=bday, Email=Email, Password=generate_password_hash(Password, method='sha256'))
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            flash("account created!", category='Succes')
            return redirect(url_for('views.home'))

    return render_template("signup.html")


@auth.route('/Logout')
def signup():
    pass
```

Comment: Have you checked what's _in_ the database? Maybe you created the db before without the column?

Comment: no i've checked the database and i haven't made a database without the column